# Normal force by String

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, string

Can, in any condition, the string or string-like objects provide normal force to any object getting supported by it?  Maybe when the string is taut!!

Comment: What's the difference between this and tension?

Comment: I don't think i get you. Normal as in perpendicular to the string? Or normal to the object?

Comment: @Sam but it still might be able to support a spherical cow.

Comment: What do you mean by "getting supported by string ?". There are many ways how object can be supported by a string,- can you show a sketch of your string supporting scheme ?

Comment: @Sam Can a massless string not exert a force? What about string tension?

Comment: Normal force is a force perpendicular to a surface, and exerted by that surface. Tension in a string is a force in the direction of the string. There is no way I can see to confuse these absolutely distinct ideas.

Answer (score 1):

It was not specified the exact string supporting scheme, but I will risk and assume that OP had this in mind :

[image]

Assuming mass-less string and according to Hooke's law and force equilibrium condition :

$$ -k\, x_0 + m\,g = 0 $$

So the answer in this case is,- yes string restoration force is a normal force type which reacts to weight/pressure applied.

Comment: "$-kx_0+mg=0$": Only true if the hanging string is perfectly straight, which it isn't.

Comment: If this is what the OP had in mind, then it seems the analysis would be the same as if the string were attached to the side  and/or the object modeled as a point particle.   Then is the question about nomenclature?  Normal or tension?  (BTW, the string wouldn't curve in the way that you drew it.).   The OP needs to clarify the question.

Comment: @garyp Agree about bad depiction of curving, should be straight lines going to both sides. But about just nomenclature I'm not sure. As for me - tension force acts in parallel to string direction, but this normal force is perpendicular component of tension force. So there's a subtle difference.

Comment: The object in the sketch could be the pulley supporting s person riding down a zip line. The angle of the line (from the horizontal) behind the person would have to a little larger than the one ahead.

Comment: @R.W.Bird I had in mind static situation, i.e. artist balancing on the middle of the rope. In this case those angles are equal.